# How to use the same authorization pipeline for WebAPI with SignalR

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I am adding signalr functionality to a website that only logged in users will have access to for communicating with each other.  I also would like to use the same pipeline to allow azure worker roles to communicate with a user indicating job statuses for long running queue-based processes, running on their behalf.  I found an example here at this url that outlines how to use the OAuth Bearer tokens with signalr: `http://blog.marcinbudny.com/search?q=Authentication+signalr+OAuth+#.V5KBaY52xTM`.  The problem is that his example seems to turn off the `OAuthBearerTokens` which I am using in my code for web api authentication and authorization.  Here is the code from the article:

```
//app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
//app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
//app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);

app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Provider = new ApplicationOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider(),
});
```

and this is my code utilizing the technique in this article:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
PublicClientId = "self";
// Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
    // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserFactory),
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(2),
        AllowInsecureHttp = false
    };

    app.Map("/signalr", map =>
    {
        map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        map.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            Provider = new QueryStringOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider()
        });

        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
        {
            Resolver = GlobalHost.DependencyResolver,
        };
        map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    });
```

How can I allow signalr to access the user's information in the same way I would for web api when there are times I will need worker role processes to pass information to clients as well as client-side code does?